# Paging in a scaffolding view MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, paging, scaffolding

so using EF4 I create a scaffolding controller/view, so my question is how can I Add Paging to my view in easy/fast way??
the
**controller** generated

```
public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Perifericos.ToList());
        }
```

the
**view:** generated

```
@model IEnumerable<Paginacion.Models.Perifericos>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Nombre
        </th>
        <th>
            Modelo
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Modelo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.idPerifericos }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.idPerifericos })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this can help you: http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

You have to implement a paging in controller and in the view add code like the link that i have given to you.

Answer (score 2):

I use this one http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/
It's support also ajax and areas

Easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

a complete msdn article with [sample code](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=215669)

[Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)